# ORA_02201 Sequence is not allowed here

Tags: java, json, spring, oracle

hope you all doing well. I'm continuously getting "ORA_02201 - Sequence is not allowed here" SQL syntax error when I'm trying to post new entry to Database using JSON. I'm using Oracle Autonomous Database
In Oracle Database, folks use GenerationType.SEQUENCE strategy for ID (Primary Key) increment.

I've tried something beforehand, let me share with you. It seems root of the issue is that Sequence is not working with JSON, or not set up to be working. It gives "Sequence is not allowed here" when my JSON request doesn't have id, so when Sequence is supposed to work.
Note that, I have this app as MVC web application where I save entity into database through getting data from form input in jsp pages. It works flawlessly and generate ID correctly. Problem is with JSON I believe.

```
{
    "firstName" : "Mark",
    "lastName" : "Heiberg",
    "email" : "heibergmark@dot.com"
}
```

I made request by specifying the Id in JSON which id exists in database, then it updated the entry.  So I get assured that root of the cause is id generation, when it should make new id, it doesn't work. I couldn't find anything about JSON-Oracle DB relationship in Internet. I wanted to ask here, maybe you know can I or should I do something to enable support for Sequence generation type on the moment of JSON request. Thanks in advance.

```
@PostMapping("/customers")
    Customer addCustomer(@RequestBody Customer customer){
        customer.setId(0); //set id to 0 to force it to  add customer to DB, instead of updating current.
        customerService.saveCustomer(customer);
        return customer;
    }
```

This is Table Definition SQL: (I've built it using Oracle APEX environtment, don't mind that 9999999999999999, it's by default)

```
CREATE TABLE  "CUSTOMER" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER(3,0) GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOKEEP  NOSCALE  NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "FIRST_NAME" VARCHAR2(15) COLLATE "USING_NLS_COMP", 
    "LAST_NAME" VARCHAR2(15) COLLATE "USING_NLS_COMP", 
    "EMAIL" VARCHAR2(30) COLLATE "USING_NLS_COMP", 
     CONSTRAINT "CUSTOMER_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE
   )  DEFAULT COLLATION "USING_NLS_COMP"
/

CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TRIGGER  "BI_CUSTOMER" 
  before insert on "CUSTOMER"               
  for each row  
begin   
  if :NEW."ID" is null then 
    select "CUSTOMER_SEQ".nextval into :NEW."ID" from sys.dual; 
  end if; 
end; 

/
ALTER TRIGGER  "BI_CUSTOMER" ENABLE
/
```

This is my Entity class where Database annotations is implemented:

```
package com.customer_tracker.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER")
public class Customer {

    public Customer() {
    }

    public Customer(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "Customer_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "Customer_SEQ", sequenceName = "CUSTOMER_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    @NotNull(message = "This field is required!")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 15, message = "Write something!")
    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull(message = "This field is required!")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 15, message = "Write something!")
    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    @NotNull(message = "This field is required!")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 30, message = "Write something!")
    @Column(name = "EMAIL")
    private String email;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName.trim().replaceAll("\\s", "");
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName.trim().replaceAll("\\s", "");
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email.trim().replaceAll("\\s", "");
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "id = " + id +
                ", firstName = " + firstName + ", lastName = " + lastName + ", email = " + email;
    }
}
```

This is the code snippet where Hibernate going to save entry to Database:

```
package com.customer_tracker.dao;

import com.customer_tracker.entity.Customer;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public class CustomerList implements CustomerDAO{

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public void saveCustomer(Customer customer) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.saveOrUpdate(customer);
    }

}
```

... `GET`, `PUT`, `DELETE` methods work as desired, only `POST` doesn't work as database should generate id behind the scenes.

Comment: can you provide a ddl of the table ??

Comment: I think you should try finding the exact SQL query which is causing the issue.

Comment: We would need your Entity code as well.

Comment: @RobertoHernandez Hello, I've added it in thread. Thank you for assistance.

Comment: Hello @JoãoDias I've added it, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using an `identity column` with the option `generated always`, but at the same time you are using a trigger to populate the column ID with a sequence. You can't do that, either you use a sequence and a trigger, or you use identity columns. If you are in Oracle 12c or higher, I strongly recommend you to use identity columns, unless some of the restrictions they inherit may affect the way your application behaves.

See this example

```
SQL> create table test_col ( c1 number generated always as identity start with 1 increment by 1 , c2 varchar2(1) ) ;

Table created.

SQL> insert into test_col ( c2 ) values ( 'A' ) ;

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test_col ;

        C1 C
---------- -
         1 A

SQL> insert into test_col ( c1,c2 ) values ( 2,'B' ) ;
insert into test_col ( c1,c2 ) values ( 2,'B' )
                       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-32795: cannot insert into a generated always identity column
```

You have to drop the trigger and the sequence as they are useless in this scenario. The error is surely raised when the trigger is fired. When you use identity columns, Oracle handles automatically for you the sequence and the insert.

The identity columns are subject to the following restrictions:

- Each table has one and only one identity column.
- The data type of the identity column must be a numeric data type. the user-defined data type is not allowed to use with the identity clause.
- The identity column is not inherited by the CREATE TABLE AS SELECTstatement.
- The identity column cannot have another DEFAULT constraint.
- The encryption algorithm for encrypted identity columns can be inferred therefore you should use a strong encryption algorithm.
- The inline constraint of the identity column must not conflict with the NOT NULL and NOT DEFERRABLE constraint stated by the identity clause.

`generated always` is one of the options for **Identity Columns**. Read more about that in the link below

[Identity Columns](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-identity-column/)

Comment: I tried to use Identity Column month ago when I started to build project as my  instructor was using MySQL Lite with IdentityColumn, but that was not worked for me (I mean I set GenerationType.IDENTITY and application caused error), so I researched a bit about what to use with oracle and decided to set up sequence, same sequence works in my MVC web application where I get data from html forms, but not working on JSON  request.

Comment: @fuadik88, then I don't get what you put the data model with a table with identity column and then a trigger trying to populate the identity column.

Comment: looks like I have to dig more into database.

Comment: disable or drop the trigger and try again. the error is being fired by the trigger

Comment: solved it, looks like identity column is problematic with ORM (JPA, Hibernate), so I dropped identity and set fresh Sequence and it worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using JPA you should have @Id and @GeneratedValue (with proper strategy) annotations over id field and it will be auto-generated.

Example: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Comment: Hi, I have MVC based version of this application and it works flawlessly, gets input (firstname, lastname, email) from html form and save it to Database by generating ID. I've  ```@Id``` and ```@GeneratedValue``` set. The issue rises in JSON request, it basically says "Sequence not allowed here" and I doubt if I should add some annotation or kind of "support" to make it work with JSON.